# Periodically fetching the auth token while the async function is running

Tags: node.js, mongodb, authorization, access-token

I have this authFetch function that fetches the token and updates it in mongo and token variable.

```
 const authFetch = async () => {

let authCollection = client.db("WheelPros_data").collection("auth");
TokenFromDB = await authCollection.find({ _id: 1 }).toArray();
({ accessToken: token, time: lastFetchedAuth } = TokenFromDB[0] || [{ accessToken: null, time: 0 }])
// console.log(new Date().getTime() / 1000 - lastFetchedAuth)

let axiosConfig = {
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    accept: "application/json",
  },
};

await axios({
  method: "POST",
  data: {
    userName: process.env.WHEELPROS_USERNAME,
    password: process.env.PASSWORD,
  },
  url: `${process.env.PROD_API_URL}/auth/v1/authorize`,
  axiosConfig,
})
  .then(async (res) => {
    const { accessToken } = res.data;
    authCollection.updateOne(
      { _id: 1 },
      {
        $set: {
          accessToken: accessToken,
          time: new Date().getTime() / 1000,
          Date: new Date(),
        },
      }, {
      upsert: true
    }
    );
    console.log("newAccessToken : ", accessToken)
    token = await accessToken
    console.log("inside token var = ", token)

    console.log("------------------Auth Updated------------------");

  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log("AXIOS ERROR: ", err);
  });
}
await authFetch()
// console.log("ourside token var = ", token)

setInterval(authFetch, 3590000)
```

Problem arises when i call another async function to fetch the submodels. After 1 hour the token expires and that is why we have setInterval function to update the token but it does not update the token and i get hit with the 403 error

Below is the modelFetch function

```
 const fetchSubmodels = async () => {
const modelDataFromDB = await collection
  .find({ modelData: { $exists: true } })
  .toArray();
console.log(modelDataFromDB.length)
modelDataFromDB.forEach(async (modeldata) => {
  // await fetchToken().catch(console.error)

  let dataSearch = modeldata.modelData.split(';')

  await axios
    .get(
      `${process.env.PROD_API_URL}/${dataSearch[0]}/makes/${dataSearch[1]}/models/${dataSearch[2]}/submodels`,
      {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
      }
    )
    .then(async function ({ data }) {

      await collection.updateOne(
        { modelData: modeldata.modelData },
        {
          $set: {
            submodels: data
          },
        }
      );
      // handle success
      console.log(`pushing the submodels ${data} to ${modeldata.modelData} `)

    })
    .catch(async function (error) {
      // handle error
      console.log(error);

    })

})
}
await fetchSubmodels()
clearInterval(authFetch)
```

Any insights would be helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like [`array.map`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73755417/16462950), `array.forEach` does not `await` the result of the function that it calls. In your case, this means that the `axios.get` statements for each entry in `modelDataFromDB` send out all requests synchronously, while `token` still has its original value. (Therefore they should never lead to 403, if they reach the backend in time.)

What's more, `fetchSubmodels` does not `await` anything and therefore resolves after all these requests have been sent out. At that point in time `await fetchSubmodels()` is completed, therefore `clearInterval(authFetch)` is executed almost immediately, and the `setInterval` has no effect.

While this does not yet explain the 403 responses, it is certainly not what you intended.

If you replace

```js
modelDataFromDB.forEach(async (modeldata) => {
  ...
})
```

with

```js
for (var modeldata of modelDataFromDB) {
  ...
}
```

the requests will be sent consecutively, and `fetchSubmodels` will await the response of the last request.